# Unable to load the recipients group when sending mailing with Civimail

Tags: civimail, groups

I am running CiviCRM 5.17.4 on Wordpress 5.2.3. The problem I am facing is that 
 I am unable to send mailing to mailing lists (defined as groups) via CiviMail.

When I try to enter the group in the **Recipients** box I get **Loading Failed** message and none of the available groups is loaded (see image below). The problem appears for existing and new mailings.

Interestingly when I re-use the existing mailing I can still send it to a previously used group (though I cannot change the recipient lists). The groups load normally in manage group page.

Any advice on the problem or debugging suggestions would be very welcomed.

[image: image[1]]

Comment: Is this something that should be reported as a bug or is this specific to my installation?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was caused by some server settings by my hosting provider (apparently they did some changes to the firewall). They managed to fix it and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: It would be great to know what the problem/solution was. I have the same situation. Not sure what to try.