# "Loading Failed" when selecting recipient group in Civimail mailing

Tags: civimail, groups

I know this has been [asked before](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33070/unable-to-load-the-recipients-group-when-sending-mailing-with-civimail), but in that case the problem was fixed without identifying the problem or the solution.

I'm trying to send mails using CiviMail, but when I try to select mailing group in the include group or exclude groups, an error "Loading failed" appears. The browser console shows a 500 error, which makes me think the problem may be with the server, not the CiviCRM installation, but I'm not sure what to try. The problem started happening a couple of months ago. I've tried different php versions, different browsers, restarting the server, rebuilding the cache. I can't see anything relevant in the system log or the CiviCRM log. Any suggestions what else I could try to find the problem? Thank you.

CiviCRM version 5.65.2 (but i think it began several versions ago).
CMS is WP. Php 8.1 or 7.4.

Comment: Is the problem consistent or intermittent? Can you verify that the `civi_mail` *extension* (not just the component but also the extension) is enabled? Also verify that `search_kit` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. It's consistent. Yes, civi_mail extension and search_kit are both enabled. I don't know if it's relevant, but search_kit and flexmailer are both marked as Required, so can't be disabled.

Comment: Just noticed that there's a 500 error showing in the console when I open the mailing: POST https://domain.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/api4/EntitySet/autocomplete

Comment: And an "Uncaught error (in promise) from /wp-admin/admin.php?…a/#/mailing/630:1

Comment: We had something similar - the autocomplete for the group search was trying to fetch the data with non-https hence the failure. Maybe worth looking into?

Comment: Thank you @RebeccaTregenna. Can you remember what the fix was? I tried disabling ModSecurity but that didn't help.

Comment: If I've interpreted it correctly, the browser console indicates a syntax error at the following line in jquery.min.js

return T.querySelector(":has(*,:jqfake)")

code: 12
message: "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': ':has(*,:jqfake)' is not a valid selector."
name: "SyntaxError"

Comment: OK, I've had to give up. I've run out of ideas for debugging. I can fiddle the mailings by adding the inclusions and exclusions directly in the mailing_group table. If anyone can suggest any more debugging ideas, that would be great.

Comment: @RebeccaTregenna - we are having exactly the problem you mention: the autocomplete is trying to fetch data with http. I've tried everything I can think of to resolve it, and the only thing that works so far is switching from nginx to apache... but that breaks a few other things. Do you recall how you resolved it?

Comment: @zip_000 we added some settings in the Drupal settings.php file to support reverse proxy in case that helps (not sure what CMS you are on)

Comment: @RebeccaTregenna - thanks! Also on Drupal. I was able to get things working correctly under Nginx by adding an additional header. It was a lot of trial and error to get there though.

Comment: @zip_000 Congratulations. What was the additional header which did the trick? Can you give any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: @Jern - in the http section of nginx.conf I added: `map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_param_https_variable {
    default '$scheme';
    https 'on';
}` and in the server - location section of the site configuration file, I added `fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_param_https_variable;` This was a throwing everything at the wall to see what sticks situation though, so I can't say what it was exactly. The last piece though was adding the $scheme to the map section.